# Bottom tray dissapeared - Can't open minimised windows - 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04

So i am accessing my Ubuntu server via tightVNC - and now i have no tray at the bottom and some other clickable items on the top right (I may have pressed something but, I'm not too sure). Hence i can't open minimized applications etc.

[image: Screenshot of desktop]

Info:
Ubuntu LTS 14.04
tightVNC via putty

Answer (score 0):

Right click -> Applications -> Settings -> Panel -> Yes